# Iterating through XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <NConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <NDomain>ex1</NDomain>
            <Parameters>
                <version>p</version>
                <siteFolder>site1</siteFolder>
                <cssGeneral></cssGeneral>
                <cssLogin>l.css</cssLogin>
            </Parameters>
            <Database>
                <hostname>898</hostname>
                <username>j</username>
                <password>k</password>
                <name>n</name>
            </Database>
<NDomain>ex2</NDomain>
                <Parameters>
                    <version>p</version>
                    <siteFolder>site1</siteFolder>
                    <cssGeneral></cssGeneral>
                    <cssLogin>l.css</cssLogin>
                </Parameters>
                <Database>
                    <hostname>898</hostname>
                    <username>j</username>
                    <password>k</password>
                    <name>n</name>
                </Database>
        </NConfig>
```

I would like to itterate through all the nodes under ex1

So far, I can directly access the nodes by doing this:

```
$xmldata  = simplexml_load_file("config.xml");

foreach($xmldata->Parameters as $item)
{
        echo "<p>Version: " . $item->version . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Site Folder: " . $item->siteFolder . "</p>";
}
```

But that doesn't make it root node specific, rather it will iterate though all of the parameters in the list. How can I do this?

Comment: can you please elaborate on "root node specific" ??

Comment: Just edited it - so that you have specific parameter nodes belonging to their respective root nodes: <NDomain>ex2</NDomain>
 etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `<Parameters>` and `<Database>` be specfic for the corresponding `<NDomain>` , I prefer you should have ur xml schema like this:

```
     <NDomain>
            <name>ex1</name>
            <Parameters>
                <version>p</version>
                <siteFolder>site1</siteFolder>
                <cssGeneral></cssGeneral>
                <cssLogin>l.css</cssLogin>
            </Parameters>
            <Database>
                <hostname>898</hostname>
                <username>j</username>
                <password>k</password>
                <name>n</name>
            </Database>
      </NDomain>
      <NDomain>
        <name>ex2</name>
                <Parameters>
                    <version>p</version>
                    <siteFolder>site1</siteFolder>
                    <cssGeneral></cssGeneral>
                    <cssLogin>l.css</cssLogin>
                </Parameters>
                <Database>
                    <hostname>898</hostname>
                    <username>j</username>
                    <password>k</password>
                    <name>n</name>
                </Database>
      </NDomain>
```

So you can parse like this :

```
   foreach($xmldata->NDomain as $item)
   {
     $par = $item->Parameters;
    echo "<p>Version: " . $par->version . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Site Folder: " . $par->siteFolder . "</p>";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the root nodes children, like this:

```
$first = true;
foreach($xmldata->children() as $item)
{
    if( $first === true) { 
        $first = false;
        continue;
    }
}
```

That loop will catch `<NDomain>`, `<Parameters>`, and `<Database>`, so you'll need a simple check to skip the first iteration to omit `<NDomain>`.

Comment: Right so I use an if before the foreach?